# How to add tkinter progress bar indeterminate with function

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, ttk

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def DOTEST_GUI():
    GUI = Tk()
    w = 1920
    h = 1080
    ws = GUI.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = GUI.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    GUI.geometry(f'{w}x{h}+{x:.0f}+{y:.0f}')

    def start_p():
        progress.start(5)

    def stop_P():
        progress.stop()

    def print_cf(event = None):
        import time
        print('s')
        start_p()
        time.sleep(5)
        stop_P()

    B_TEST = ttk.Button(GUI, text = "test", width = 15, command = print_cf)
    B_TEST.pack()

    progress = ttk.Progressbar(GUI, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 100, mode = 'indeterminate')
    progress.pack(pady = 10)

    GUI.bind("<Return>", print_cf)

    GUI.focus()
    GUI.mainloop()

DOTEST_GUI()
```

follow this code progress bar is not running properly.

I tried to remove `stop_P()`, it's work after 5 second of `time.sleep(5)`.

I would like it to start running progress 5 second until the `stop_P()` code.

Comment: def start_p():
        progress.start(5)
        print_cf
        time.sleep(5)
        progress.stop()

Comment: B_TEST = ttk.Button(GUI, text = "test", width = 15, command = start_p

Comment: There is something wrong on my pc. I cannot  stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a `Progressbar` for a set amount of time and then stop it, you could do something like this.  Consolidate the `print_cf` function to start and stop the progress and set a range of 5, sleep for 1 second in between and then stop the `Progressbar`. Placing it on a thread would allow you to do something more time consuming than sleeping one second and printing something.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import threading



                    
def DOTEST_GUI():
    GUI = Tk()
    w = 1920
    h = 1080
    ws = GUI.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = GUI.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    GUI.geometry(f'{w}x{h}+{x:.0f}+{y:.0f}')


    def run_thread():
        execute_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_cf)
        execute_thread.start()

        
    def print_cf(event = None):
        progress.start()
        print('s')
        for i in range(5):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)
            if i ==4:
                progress.stop()


    B_TEST = ttk.Button(GUI, text = "test", width = 15, command = run_thread)
    B_TEST.pack()

    progress = ttk.Progressbar(GUI, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 100, mode = 'indeterminate')
    progress.pack(pady = 10)

    GUI.bind("<Return>", print_cf)

    GUI.focus()
    GUI.mainloop()
        

DOTEST_GUI()
```